# Binary system, how can i calculate

Tags: math, binary, equation, calculation

I got three equations.

1) 0+0=0

2) 1+0=1

3) 1+1=10

---

I have to calculate this with the help of the three equations

i) 1+0+0+0=?

ii) 0+1+0=?

iii) 1+1+0=?

But I don't know how to start

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously homework so I'm not going to give you the answers. Instead, I'll leave you a few hints.

`0 + 1 + 0 = (0 + 1) + 0 = (1 + 0) + 0`

`1 + 1 + 0 = (1 + 1) + 0 = 10 + 0`

Binary and Decimal represent the same numbers just in a different way.
You can check your answers using the following mapping from **decimal** to **binary**.

```
              Decimal      -> Binary 
      0 =  0  + 0   + 0    -> 0
      1 =  0  + 0   + 2^0  -> 1
      2 =  0  + 2^1 + 0    -> 10
      3 =  0  + 2^1 + 2^0  -> 11
      4 = 2^2 + 0   + 0    -> 100
      5 = 2^2 + 0   + 2^0  -> 101
      6 = 2^2 + 2^1 + 0    -> 110
      7 = 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0  -> 111
```

and so on.

Comment: but then i) and ii) would be the same? --> (1+0)+(0+0) = 1 + 0 = 1

Comment: Exactly, try converting this from binary to decimal to check your answer. I'll update my answer with a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Binary is just another way of writing the same old same old numbers. What is 1+1 in a normal amount number system? When you add numbers together you can be transitive normally:

```
(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)
```

and

```
a+b = b+a
```